# Using templates to implement a generic filter

Tags: c++, templates

I have a filter which is supposed to work on arbitrary tensors. For my case it is sufficient when the filter works on rank 1,2 and 3 tensors which are lists, matrices and 3d-matrices or volumes respectively. Additionally, the filter can be applied in each possible direction. For a list this is only one, for matrices exist 2 possible directions (namely X-direction and y-direction) and for volumes exist 3 possible direction.

**Before I go into detail let me ask my question first:** Is my layout of the filter ok or did I forgot something important which maybe gives me a hard time later? I'm not new to C++ templates, but it's not that I feel like a fish in water. Is it possible to compress this layout further (maybe there's a way around the dummy `XDirection` classes or a shorter `Type2Type`)?

The basic procedure of the filter is for every tensor-rank and for every direction the same. There is just a few lines of code, the function `callKernel`, which are different. To make the overloaded `operator()` call the right `callKernel` function is the only interesting part in the code below. Since partial specialization for templates does not work for class-methods, you can convert the template arguments into a real class-type and give this as dummy argument to `callKernel`.

The following code is they layout up to rank 2. It is compileable with `g++` and can be tried.

```
template <class DataType, int Rank>
class Tensor { };

class XDirection;
class YDirection;

template <class TensorType, class Direction>
struct Type2Type {
  typedef TensorType TT;
  typedef Direction D;
};

template <class TensorType, class Direction>
struct Filter {
  Filter(const TensorType &t){}
  TensorType operator()(){
    /* much code here */
    callKernel(Type2Type<TensorType,Direction>());
    /* more code */
    TensorType result;
    return result;
  } 
  void callKernel(Type2Type<Tensor<double,1>, XDirection>) {} 
  void callKernel(Type2Type<Tensor<double,2>, XDirection>) {}
  void callKernel(Type2Type<Tensor<double,2>, YDirection>) {}
};

int main(void) {
  Tensor<double, 2> rank_two_tensor;
  Filter<Tensor<double,2>,XDirection> f(rank_two_tensor);
  f();
}
```

Let me add some important things: It is necessary that the filter-logic is in the `operator()` because what you see here is going used with the *Intel Threading Building Blocks* which require this structure. It is very important, that the `callKernel` is inlined. From everything I know, this should be the case.

Thanks in advance for any helpful and critical comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, not bad for a first try on templates.

If you have a recent version of GCC you can simplify like this, there's a better way to execute code conditionally on a type using `std::is_same<>`. It will return `true` if the types are identical. It also makes your intent more explict.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class TensorType, class Direction> 
struct Filter { 
  Filter(const TensorType &t) { } 

  TensorType operator()(){ 
    /* much code here */ 
    callKernel(); 
    /* more code */ 
    TensorType result; 
    return result; 
  }  

  void callKernel() {
      // Check which type is called at compile time (the if will be simplified by the compiler)
      if (std::is_same<TensorType, Tensor<double, 2> >::value) {
          if (std::is_same<Direction, XDirection>::value) {
              // do stuff
          } else {
              ...
          }
      } else if (...) {
          ...
      }
  }  
};
```

Edit: If you wish you can even move it to `op()` to make sure the code is inlined.

Comment: +1 Thanks, that's shorter. I got my idea from "Modern C++ Desing". The `is_same` calls are determined at compile-time and converted to constants, right? Is there a chance, that the compiler optimizes the if-else statements out? I know, it's only one condition.. I'm just curious.

Comment: Well, to be honest I don't usually check the optimizations that I think my compiler will do. In that special case I am pretty confident it will happen if you use a recent enough compiler. The only way for you to be sure is to look a the disassembly ... Don't forget to compile with optimizations enabled and not in debug mode.

Comment: I *think* that "Modern C++ Design" is older than `std::is_same`, but I came to C++ after both so I can't confirm ;).